# axios abort all request when one fails

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, axios, cancellation

I have a line of multiple pending requests

```
const requests = [];

requests.push(axios.post('/request1', {moo:1});
requests.push(axios.post('/request2', {moo:2});
requests.push(axios.post('/request3', {moo:3});

Promise.all(requests).then((reponse) => {
    debugger;
}).catch((err) => {
    debugger;
});
```

and if one of them fails I am trying to abort all.
Unfortunately currently if one fails the next request is still made.

I've tried some cancellation code but the next request still triggers

```
const requests = [];
const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
const cancelToken = source.token;

requests.push(axios.post('/request1', {moo:1}, {cancelToken} );
requests.push(axios.post('/request2', {moo:2}, {cancelToken} );
requests.push(axios.post('/request3', {moo:3}, {cancelToken} );

Promise.all(requests).then((reponse) => {
    debugger;
}).catch((err) => {
    source.cancel("Request canceled");
    debugger;
});
```

Comment: *"...but the next request still triggers..."* What do you mean by "still triggers"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is still executed and the request lands on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried some cancellation code but the next request still triggers

You're **starting** the requests here (if I assume a closing `)` on each line):

```
requests.push(axios.post('/request1', {moo:1}, {cancelToken} ));
requests.push(axios.post('/request2', {moo:2}, {cancelToken} ));
requests.push(axios.post('/request3', {moo:3}, {cancelToken} ));
```

At that point, the requests are underway. `Promise.all` doesn't **run** anything, it *observes* things that are *already* running.

Your code using a cancellation token will cancel the requests where possible when the rejection handler you have on `Promise.all`'s promise runs, but unless you run your requests in series (one at at time), they'll all *start* before that happens.

If you want to do them in series, the easiest way is with an `async` function:

```
async function postInSeries(iterable) {
    // Does the requests in series
    const results = [];
    for (const request of iterable) {
        results.push(await axios.post(...request));
    }
    return results;
}
// ...
postInSeries([
    ['/request1', {moo:1}],
    ['/request2', {moo:2}],
    ['/request3', {moo:3}],
])
.then(results => {
    // ...use the results...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

Comment: Can I abort them all in some way still or if that isn't possible what pattern should I use that gives me abortion control?

Comment: @BatMan - That's what the cancellation token does, it cancels the in-progress request where possible. But of course, once it's reached the server, it's reached the server and all you're doing is cancelling processing the response. (Also possibly closing the connection, which the server may or may not see and be able to use to stop doing its work.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom lib you can do the following ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-all-concurrent-requests-generator-31ekf?file=/src/index.js)):

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";
import CPAxios from "cp-axios";

(async (urls) => {
  try {
    const responses = await CPromise.all(
      function* () {
        for (const url of urls) {
          yield CPAxios(url);
        }
      },
      { concurrency: 3 } // optionally
    );
    console.log(responses);
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(`Fail: ${err}`);
  }
})([
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/3",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/4",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/5",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/BadID",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/7",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/8"
]);
```

Or with mapper function ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-all-concurrent-requests-mapper-1c6u7?file=/src/index.js)):

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";
import CPAxios from "cp-axios";

(async (urls) => {
  try {
    const responses = await CPromise.all(urls, {
      mapper(url) {
        return CPAxios(url);
      },
      concurrency: 3
    });
    console.log(responses);
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(`Fail: ${err}`);
  }
})([
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/3",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/4",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/5",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/BadID",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/7",
  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/8"
]);
```